# Aggregate strings using c() in dplyr summarize or aggregate

Tags: r, string, aggregate, dplyr

I want to aggregate some strings using c() as aggregation function in dplyr. I first tried the following:

```
> InsectSprays$spray = as.character(InsectSprays$spray)
> dt = tbl_df(InsectSprays)
> dt %>% group_by(count) %>% summarize(c(spray))
Error: expecting a single value
```

But using c() function in aggregate() works:

```
> da = aggregate(spray ~ count, InsectSprays, c)
> head(da)
  count                  spray
1     0                   C, C
2     1       C, C, C, C, E, E
3     2             C, C, D, E>
```

Searching in stackoverflow [hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785974/string-manipulation-agregation-in-dplyr) that instead of c() function, using paste() with collapse would solve the problem:

```
dt %>% group_by(count) %>% summarize(s=paste(spray, collapse=","))
```

or

```
dt %>% group_by(count) %>% summarize(paste( c(spray), collapse=","))
```

My question is: Why does c() function work in aggregate() but not in dplyr summarize()?

Comment: You can also use `toString()` which is the same as `paste(.. , collapse = ", ")`

Comment: I think one difference is that `c()` returns a vector while `paste(.. , collapse = ", ")` and `toString` return a single string. (which doesnt really answer your question, I know). To see that, compare the differences between `str(aggregate(cyl ~ hp, mtcars, toString))` and `str(aggregate(cyl ~ hp, mtcars, c))`.

Comment: You could use `data.table` for bigger datasets if you want the `list` column ie. `DT1 <- data.table(InsectSprays);DT1[, list(spray=list(spray)), keyby=count]`

Comment: Did you really want to have list items in the aggregated column or was it just because you didn't notice (since it's not obvious from looking at the output of `aggregate`)?

Comment: @beginneR: Actually, I didn't notice that. Thank you for making this subtle difference explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a closer look, you can find that `c()` actually does work (to a certain extent) when we use `do()`.  But to my understanding, `dplyr` does not currently allow this type of printing of lists

```
> InsectSprays$spray = as.character(InsectSprays$spray)
> dt = tbl_df(InsectSprays)
> doC <- dt %>% group_by(count) %>% do(s = c(.$spray))
> head(doC)
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

  count        s
1     0 <chr[2]>
2     1 <chr[6]>
3     2 <chr[4]>
4     3 <chr[8]>
5     4 <chr[4]>
6     5 <chr[7]>

> head(doC)[[2]]
[[1]]
[1] "C" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "E" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "C" "D" "E"

[[4]]
[1] "C" "C" "D" "D" "E" "E" "E" "E"

[[5]]
[1] "C" "D" "D" "E"

[[6]]
[1] "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E"
```

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with summarise too, see https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/832

Comment: @hadley please post this as a separate answer, I think it should be the preferred way.